# tightvnc on Linux Mint says "could not acquire name on session bus"

Tags: linux-mint, vnc, remote-desktop, remmina, tightvnc

I have two linux machines running Linux Mint 19.3.

I just install tightvnc server on one of them from apt. On the other I install remmina and remmina vnc plugin.

I run vncserver on the host and it outputs to the console...

```
New 'X' desktop is scott-Z97-HD3:1

Starting applications specified in /etc/X11/Xvnc-session
Log file is /home/scott/.vnc/scott-Z97-HD3:1.log
```

I then connect to the server using the other machine on Remmina. It seems to connect fine and enter remote desktop view.

Unfortunately, all that is show is a dark background with a window box that displays the text...

```
could not acquire name on session bus
```

When I click the only button that says "logout", it just logs out and kills the client session.

Is there something I am missing here for configuration?

Here are the logs..

```
11/05/19 11:43:32 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
11/05/19 11:43:32 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
11/05/19 11:43:32 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
11/05/19 11:43:32 All Rights Reserved.
11/05/19 11:43:32 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
11/05/19 11:43:32 Desktop name 'X' (scott-Z97-HD3:1)
11/05/19 11:43:32 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
11/05/19 11:43:32 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
No VNC extension on display :1
11/05/19 11:43:40 Got connection from client 192.168.100.102
11/05/19 11:43:40 Using protocol version 3.8
11/05/19 11:43:40 Full-control authentication passed by 192.168.100.102
11/05/19 11:43:40 Pixel format for client 192.168.100.102:
11/05/19 11:43:40   16 bpp, depth 16, little endian
11/05/19 11:43:40   true colour: max r 31 g 63 b 31, shift r 11 g 5 b 0
11/05/19 11:43:40 Using tight encoding for client 192.168.100.102
11/05/19 11:43:40 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
11/05/19 11:43:40 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 9
11/05/19 11:43:40 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -65527
11/05/19 11:43:40 Using compression level 3 for client 192.168.100.102
11/05/19 11:43:40 Using image quality level 7 for client 192.168.100.102
11/05/19 11:43:40 Enabling X-style cursor updates for client 192.168.100.102
11/05/19 11:43:40 Enabling cursor position updates for client 192.168.100.102
11/05/19 11:43:40 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -131072
11/05/19 11:43:40 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
11/05/19 11:43:40 Enabling LastRect protocol extension for client 192.168.100.102
11/05/19 11:43:40 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -131071
11/05/19 11:43:40 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -131070
11/05/19 11:43:40 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -131069
11/05/19 11:43:40 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -309 Killing Xtightvnc process ID 14
```

Answer (score 2):

### Solution 1

Unset the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable by adding the following line to `~/.vnc/xstartup`:

```
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

If this doesn't work it is possible that you are having the same issue as mentioned [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1381034#c10). Add the above line to the `/etc/sysconfig/desktop` file instead.

### Solution 2

It is possible that `xinitrc` doesn't have execution permissions:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

### Solution 3

Apparently it is possible that `chrome-remote-desktop` is installed and this may cause problems:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove chrome-remote-desktop
```

[Source](https://themillers.club/2018/07/25/linux-mint-19-chrome-remote-desktop-could-not-acquire-name-on-session-bus-error-on-login/)

Comment: vncserver did not create an xstartup file.....is that normal? Should I create one myself?

Comment: also , I have no etc/sysconfig/desktop

Comment: (Solution 1) Solved the "could not acquire ..." problem for me, but now on to my next issue which reads "Cinnamon just crashed, do you want to restart Cinnamon" - (it's progress! :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-debian-10

I had similar problem and resolved by backing up xstartup file and create a new one:

contents of `~/.vnc/xstartup` file

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
```

---

```
sudo chmod +x ~/.vnc/xstartup
```